# Whats the proper way to send a big file to an android device via json-rpc service?

Tags: php, android, api, json-rpc

im writing json-rpc service that provides an android app with some data. now i needa send a file that is huge enough to refuse the idea of encoding it to base64. more than that, the file link won't work either, cuz im not allowed to store files on server and any data transfer should be proven by sending a jwt token from the app, so whats the best way for me to do this. thank you in advance.

Comment: You should at least state a ballpark size as "big" could mean 10MB to one person and 10GB to another.

Comment: actually, it's like 60KB. i heard base64 encoding can be used when it's up to 20KB.

Comment: Lol base64 encoding has no length limit. The only drawback is that the encoded data is 33% larger than the input.

Comment: exactly, it makes then output is quite huge and massive, thats the reason why im looking for another way. what would you do? would you still be using base64 in this case?

Comment: I would post my code in a new question so that people can evaulate it with their eyeballs rather than imagining what it might be based on vague description. Also, I wouldn't literally try to read a raw POST request.